# Efficiently accumulate sign bits in arm neon

Tags: c++, arm, intrinsics, neon

I have a loop that does some computations and then stores sign bits into a vector:

```
uint16x8_t rotate(const uint16_t* x);

void compute(const uint16_t* src, uint16_t* dst)
{
    uint16x8_t sign0 = vmovq_n_u16(0);
    uint16x8_t sign1 = vmovq_n_u16(0);
    for (int i=0; i<16; ++i)
    {
        uint16x8_t r0 = rotate(src++);
        uint16x8_t r1 = rotate(src++);
        // pseudo code:
        sign0 |= (r0 >> 15) << i;
        sign1 |= (r1 >> 15) << i;
    }
    vst1q_u16(dst+1, sign0);
    vst1q_u16(dst+8, sign1);
}
```

What's the best way to accumulate sign bits in neon that follows that pseudo code?

[Here's what I came up with](https://godbolt.org/g/gkuVHh):

```
    r0 = vshrq_n_u16(r0, 15);
    r1 = vshrq_n_u16(r1, 15);
    sign0 = vsraq_n_u16(vshlq_n_u16(r0, 15), sign0, 1);
    sign1 = vsraq_n_u16(vshlq_n_u16(r1, 15), sign1, 1);
```

Also, note that the "pseudo code" actually works and generates pretty much the same code perf wise. What can be improved here? Note, in actual code there is no function calls in the loop, I trimmed down actual code to make it simple to understand.
Another point: in neon you cannot use a variable for vector shift (e.g. `i` cannot use used to specify number of shifts).

Comment: Is `vsraq` an arithmetic shift, rather than logical?  Why use that?  Also, you could use fewer shifts if you use AND to zero the non-sign bits before shifting.  like `sign0 |= (r0 & 0x8000) >> (15-i);`  Or with a fixed shift count: `sign0 |= (r0 & 0x8000);  sign0 >>= 1;`  The latter should be easy and efficient to implement with SIMD, but I don't know ARM well.

Comment: [VSRA](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0473j/dom1361289988387.html) is Vector Shift Right by immediate value and Accumulate. `_u16` vs `_s16` would define logical vs arithmetic shift.

Comment: Oh, so you're isolating the sign bit with `(x >> 15) << 15` instead of `x & 0x8000`.  Looks like you could use `vsra` to easily implement the 2nd suggestion in my previous comment in 2 instructions: `tmp = r0 & 0x8000; sign0 = (sign0 >> 1) + tmp;`

Comment: for & 0x8000 I'd need to create a q-register and I'm not sure if I have enough in the loop. I'll try that to see if I get better results. Two shifts aren't complicated, except that AFAIK in neon there is only one shifter unit, but compiler spreads the shifts in generated code.

Comment: can you put it as an answer, I think it should be better than my code

Comment: Yeah you need a vector constant.  A SIMD barrel shifter is a lot more complicated than a bitwise boolean ALU, for example on x86 Haswell only has 1 per clock throughput for SIMD integer shifts, but 3 per clock for SIMD integer booleans.  And you already need at least 1 shift.  So it's not unlikely that you'd bottleneck on SIMD shift throughput, unless your loop is big enough with lots of other operations that can use other ports to balance it out.

Comment: Surprisingly, generated code [is absolutely identical](https://godbolt.org/g/Fh6p7p).

Comment: Huh, I didn't know you could use `clang -target arm64` on Godbolt!!  Also, is VSRA not a real instruction?  Or is clang just pessimising the intrinsic into separate `vshr` and `vorr` instructions?

Comment: * in neon you cannot use a variable for vector shift*  The ARM32 gcc output you linked on my answer includes `vshl.s16 q4, q4, q9`, so I think you're mistaken.  Or did you mean it's not as efficient?

Comment: I mean you'd need to load `i` counter to a q-register to use variable shift

Comment: Oh right.  I hope gcc is using a `vadd` to increment a vector counter separately from the GP register loop counter, rather than actually copying + broadcasting the loop counter every iteration.

Comment: How large is the chunk of data? Is it a multiple of 64?

Comment: Which one? `src` , `dst`, and `rotate` were added for the example only. The point is that part of the loop while calculating other stuff I need to accumulate signs into two separate q-vectors.

Comment: How many sign bits are to be collected total? Only 16?

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE Yes, 16 sign bits (times 2, times 8 for sign0 and sign1 vars, and each storing u16x8 vectors).

Comment: I don't get it. Two u16x8 vectors are 256bits total. Please be more explicit.

Comment: And you should reconsider `vsra` as well as `vsri`. Both are very slow, and they don't  allow separate target register, thus not very flexible. I wonder why someone needs either for collecting bits.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE the sample function provided basically does that. 16 bits accumulated as shown over 8 lanes, two variables. I agree about `vsra`, it allows shift right + accumulate in one instruction, but then result of `vsra` needs to be moved to `sign0`.anyways.

Comment: I'm typing on my phone, hence I cannot provide full codes right now. Get rid of the lower 8 bits by `vld2`, `vzip8`, `vmovn.16`, etc, then you only have to deal with half the data.

Comment: Then apply `vclt.s8`, with #0 to get 0xff for negative values. Then do `and` on it with {1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128}. And finally, you can make a horizontal sum. `vpadd' or `addv` on `aarch64`

Comment: In my case sign0 is result of vclt, so it's already 0xffff or 0, but what you propose works for one lane. Check provided sample code: I collect 16 sign bits, but I do that over 8 lanes in a uint16x8_t sign0 accumulator. Effectively, sign0 stores at the end 128 sign bits, and so does sign1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARM can do this in one [`vsri`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0473j/dom1361289988387.html) instruction (thanks @Jake'Alquimista'LEE).

**Given a new vector where that you want sign bits from, replace the low 15 bits of each element with the accumulator right-shifted by 1.**

You should unroll by 2 so the compiler doesn't need a `mov` instruction to copy the result back into the same register, because `vsri` is a 2-operand instruction, and the way we need to use it here gives us the result in a different register than the old `sign0` accumulator.

```
sign0 =  vsriq_n_u16(r0, sign0, 1);
// insert already-accumulated bits below the new bit we want
```

After 15 inserts, (or 16 if you start with `sign0 = 0` instead of peeling the first iteration and using sign0=r0), all 16 bits (per element) of `sign0` will be sign bits from `r0` values.

---

**Previous suggestion: AND with a vector constant to isolate the sign bit**.  It's more efficient than two shifts.

Your idea of accumulating with VSRA to shift the accumulator and add in the new bit is good, so we can keep that and get down to 2 instructions total.

```
tmp = r0 & 0x8000;            // VAND
sign0 = (sign0 >> 1) + tmp;   // VSRA
```

or using neon intrinsics:

```
uint16x8_t mask80 = vmovq_n_u16(0x8000);
r0 = vandq_u16(r0, mask80);        // VAND
sign0 = vsraq_n_u16(r0, sign0, 1); // VSRA
```

Implement with intrinsics or asm however you like, and write the scalar version the same way to give the compiler a better chance to auto-vectorize.

---

This does need a vector constant in a register.  If you're very tight on registers, then 2 shifts could be better, but 3 shifts total seems likely to bottleneck on shifter throughput unless ARM chips typically spend a lot of real-estate on SIMD barrel shifters.

In that case, maybe use this **generic SIMD idea without ARM shift+accumulate or shift+insert**

```
tmp = r0 >> 15;     // logical right shift
sign0 += sign0;     // add instead of left shifting
sign0 |= tmp;       // or add or xor or whatever.
```

**This gives you the bits in the opposite order**.  If you can produce them in the opposite order, then great.

Otherwise, does ARM have SIMD bit-reverse or only for scalar?  (Generate in reverse order and flip them at the end, with some extra work for every vector bitmap, hopefully only one instruction.)

Update: yes, AArch64 has `rbit`, so you could reverse bits within a byte, then byte-shuffle to put them in the right order.  x86 could use a `pshufb` LUT to bit-reverse within bytes in two 4-bit chunks.  This might not come out ahead of doing more work as you accumulate the bits on x86, though.

Comment: Interestingly, [no matter what I try](https://godbolt.org/g/VdLchG) clang generates the same code as if it understands my intentions and does it differently to achieve the result. However, this does work with [gcc and produces much better code](https://godbolt.org/g/5fndMg).

Comment: @Pavel: Probably clang is just compiling the `vsraq` intrinsic into it's internal representation of the operations involved, but then fails to combine them into a `vsra` asm instruction when generating code.  When compiling for x86, it often uses different shuffles than the source intrinsics, because it treats the source like source code and applies the "as-if" rule to get equivalent results.  Often this is good on x86, but it does defeat some optimizations when expressed with intrinsics.  It seems clang doesn't know how to make as good code for ARM.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense now why it does all that. By the way, you second suggestion might actually work, on arm64 there is RBIT that reverses bits (but only works on bytes).

Comment: `vsri` is better since it automatically overwrites the bits to the right, thus you need neither `and` operation nor the constant 0x8000. If you don't mind, I'll post the codes I think to be the most efficient.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE I don't see how `vsri` could be used, it's not rounding shift like [rotr/rotl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cc576c4.aspx)

Comment: Looks like sign bit can be isolated without using temporary sign mask or shifts. [`VAND.i16 r0, #0x7fff`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/CIHFBEDA.html) should do it, however, I do not see matching intrinsic for that.

Comment: ^ it, however, is inverted that way.

Comment: @Pavel: looks like `vsri` works on its own; updated the answer.  Re: `vand.i16`: ideally compilers would be smart enough to use that when there's a constant mask.  But maybe it's slower so they don't?  Or compilers just suck.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE: Thanks for the suggestion, `vsri` looks perfect.  Updated my answer, but feel free to post your own with perf analysis or optimization suggestions, or edit mine.

Comment: Oh, yes, `vsri` that works very well, totally didn't think about this approach! Thanks @Jake'Alquimista'LEE!